# Operator norm of the matrix multiplication

Tags: normed-spaces, banach-spaces, matrix-norms

Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ be a continuous matrix valued function on the compact interval $[a, b]$. Let $X = C([a, b], \mathbb R^n)$ and $Y = C([a, b], \mathbb R^m)$ be spaces of continuous functions.

Let $F: X \to Y$ such that $(F \phi)(t) = f(t) * \phi(t)$. I want to show that $||A||_{op} = \sup_{t \in [a, b]} {|f(t)|}$, where the norm of the matrix is just the operator norm.

It is pretty easy to show that $||F||_{op} \leq \sup_{t \in [a, b]} {|f(t)|}$, but I don't know how to show that it is in fact an equality.

Thanks!

Comment: As a hint, it might be helpful to consider the case when there is no dependence on $t$. When $f$ is just a matrix, and $\phi$ is just a Euclidean vector, then $F\phi = f\phi$ is just the matrix multiplication function, and its operator norm is $|f|$. How is the supremum attained in this case?

Comment: Isn't $X = C([a, b], \mathbb R^{\color{red}n})$ and $Y = C([a, b], \mathbb R^{\color{red}m})$?

Comment: Yes, you are right @azif00

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong hmm, in the case that there's no $t$ dependence it seems that it follows almost just by definition? $||F||_{op} = \sup{|f \phi| /  |\phi|} = |f|$

Comment: Right. However, your original question is about showing that $\sup_{\phi} |f \phi| / |\phi| = \sup |f|$, where $\phi$ varies with $t$. One possible way to show the equality is to find $\phi$ that attains the supremum on the right at a particular time $t^* \in [a,b]$. And answering that question reduces the problem down to the case where there's no variation in time.